# Separador de String en Java

Tags: java, sintaxis

Estoy generando un *Jtable* que tiene cierta información, sin embargo existe un campo que obtiene varios datos y se van almacenando hacia el lado dentro de la misma celda, actualmente se separan con un coma (,) pero mi problema radica en que necesito que no haya una última coma.

Por ejemplo queda así:

> Juan, Pedro, Pablo,

Así es como uno palabras:

```
String a1 = ResultSet.getString("analisis");
c += a1 + "," ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando termines de concatenar puedes usar esto:

```
c = c.replaceAll(",$", "");
```

Comment: el $ sería el valor ? en este casi a1?

Comment: No, significa el fin de linea.  Me imagino que usas un bucle.  Esto debe ser despues del bucle.

Comment: Creo que faltaría aclararle que ",$" es una expresión regular para que pueda entenderlo mejor ya que quizá piense que es un caracter

Comment: El while es un bucle.  Debes de hacerlo justo depues de terminar el while.

Comment: GRACIAS AMIGO! FUNKÓ!

Answer (score 5):

En caso estar utilizando *Java* en la versión 8 puedes utilizar el método estático `join(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence... elements)` de la clase *String* de la siguiente forma:

```
String a1 = ResultSet.getString("analisis");
String textoFinal = String.join(", ", a1, "Pedro", "Pablo");
System.out.println(textoFinal);
// Si a1 = "Juan" esto imprime:
// Juan, Pedro, Pablo
```

El primero parámetro que recibe este método es el carácter delimitador y a continuación todas las cadenas que deseas concatenar.

Para conocer más información del método puedes revisar su documentación aquí:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-

Y tal vez te resulte útil revisar esta publicación:

https://dzone.com/articles/joining-strings-in-java-8

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar esto:

```
textoFinal = textoFinal.substring(0, textoFinal.lastIndexOf(","));
```

ó bien

```
textoFinal = textoFinal.substring(0, textoFinal.length()-1);
```